# Is there any way to change the caption of a table after its declaration?

Tags: tables, floats, captions

I have some tables that are generated automatically by a third-party program. I would like to change their captions without editing their text. Is there any way to change the caption of a table after it has been declared? For example:

```
\input{file_containing_the_table}
\some_command_to_change_the_caption{new_caption}
```

where file_containing_the_table.tex is something like this:

```
\begin{table}
a tabular ...
\caption{old_caption}
\label{table_label}
\end{table}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's easier to change it before input:

```
{
\let\origcaption\caption
\def\caption#1{\origcaption{newcaption}}
\input{file_containing_the_table}
}
```

This code locally redefines `\caption` to discard its argument and instead use the original caption command with your new text.